# How to pass self from model to service object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, service-object

I wanted to move def `track_item_added` from model into service object.
  Model:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_items
  has_many :items, through: :order_items, after_add: :track_item_added

  private

  def track_item_added
   aft = AutoFillTotal.new(self)
   aft.multiply_cost_and_quantity
  end
end
```

and my service object

```
class AutoFillTotal
  def initialize(order)
   @order = order
  end

  def multiply_cost_and_quantity
   @order.items.pluck(:cost).zip(@order.order_items.pluck(:quantity)).
   map{|x, y| x * y}.sum
  end
end
```

that now in object service was in def `track_item_added` but now when I start this function as I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from (irb):2
    1: from app/models/order.rb:7:in `track_item_added'
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0))
```

May be it problem in that i pass self in constructor (new)

Comment: "problem in that i pass self in constructor" - nope, not that. Something else.

Comment: The error states that you've called the method with 1 argument, when it expects 0 arguments. This has got nothing to do with your question. What's the full stack trace? Where are you calling the method?

Comment: use only in association callback `has_many :items, through: :order_items, after_add: :track_item_added`

Comment: for test callback i run such commands in rails console: => order = Order.create; order.items << Item.first. after last command output this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> use only in association callback
>
> ```
> has_many :items, through: :order_items, after_add: :track_item_added
> ```

`after_add` callbacks expect one parameter.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/association_basics.html#association-callbacks

> Rails passes the object being added or removed to the callback.